# Jquery Select Current Element

Tags: jquery, html, hover

I have at least two "news boxes" in my website, using code like:

```
<a class="newsbox" href="#"><span>TITLE</span><div>read more</div></a>
<a class="newsbox" href="#"><span>TITLE</span><div>read more</div></a>
```

With this code, I hide the "read more" in this anchor tag:

```
jQuery("a.newsbox div").hide();
```

which works fine.

Now I want to make the "read more" visible only on the currently hovered news box.

I tried using this code :

```
jQuery("a.newsbox").hover(function() {
    jQuery(this).hover(function() {
        jQuery("div").fadeIn();
    });
});
```

but that is for all anchor tags with the class "newsbox". How can I select the current element and just show the "read more" for the current hovered element?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$('a.newsbox').hover( function(){
  $(this).find('div').fadeToggle();
});
```

By using `fadeToggle`, "read more" will also hide itself on mouseout.

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery("a.newsbox").hover(function() {
   jQuery(this).find('div').fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`jQuery('div')` is selecting all div elements on the page. You need to give it context...

```
jQuery("a.newsbox").hover(function() {
  jQuery("div", this).fadeIn();
});
```

See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
jQuery('a.newsbox').hover(function(){

   jQuery(this).children('div').fadeIn();

});
```